# what is array-backed data structure?

Tags: scala, saddle

```
 what is "array-backed" data structure?
```

I googled it, may be it is an array implemented as linked list
which could be easily appended and prepended.
Please correct me and share more updates about saddle library.

Answer (score 2):

An array-backed data structure is any data structure where the underlying values are stored in an array.  For example, a ring data structure of fixed sized can be backed by an array of that size (along with start and end indices).  Image data can have pixel values packed into an array.  Matrices (in the mathematical sense) fit naturally in arrays.

Other choices for data structures include linked lists, tries, maps (hashmaps or others); all of these have various tradeoffs.  Array-backed data structures generally work well for going through sizable chunks of data sequentially, but not for random insertion and removal of elements.

Comment: thanks Implementation of any data structure using array is also know as array backed